# Calling base function through wrong pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20

Putting aside all the good practices against writing code like below, just from the language lawyer perspective, is the following snippet legal?

```
struct Base {
  int f() { return 42; }
};
struct D1 : Base {};
struct D2 : Base {};

int main() {
  D2 d2;
  D1* ouch = reinterpret_cast<D1*>(&D2);
  return ouch->f();
}
```

It seems to me that [[class.mfct.non.static]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct.non.static) is the most relevant clause and that it suggests it is ok, as we are calling a non-static member function for an object of a derived class.

Should it happen that the non-virtual case is indeed legal, does anything change if `f` or the inheritance is virtual?

Comment: Think this is undefined behavior due to a strict aliasing violation, but I couldn't identify a standard passage that definitely says so.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11

Comment: The linked dupe is mostly irrelevant here. This question is tagged with [tag:language-lawyer] tag, which suggests that an answer directly references C++ standard.

Comment: @Evg _eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11_ how is it relevant?

Comment: https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2535.html, [which is already applied, lol](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#8)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thank you for the reference, I found that clause, but I thought it was about members, not member functions. Does it apply here too?

Comment: You can compare with the modification of the previous (existing) paragraph, where «If E2 is a non-static data member or a non-static member function» was simplified as «If E2 is a non-static member», and clearly the intent was to preserve the meaning.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thank you, could you copy your comment(s) as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

[CWG 2535](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2535.html) underlines that, unlike for unions (where common initial sequences of standard layout types can be reused), accessing class members through a pointer of distinct class type is undefined.

For an instance of practical relevance: if you used the created pointer to modify a member of `d2`, that could be rearranged with other accesses to that member during optimization, as a result of alias analysis.